# Compare Lines of Code using VS 2010 & TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Using TFS and Visual Studio 2010, is it possible to get a report of the number of lines of code each team member has written?

I know the Annotate feature allows you to see who is responsible for all of the code within a file, but is there anything that would aggregate this into a total number for each team member??

Comment: Please promise that once you have this information, you will ignore it or throw it away? LOC is (at best) a useless statistic, but in the wrong hands an LOC statistic can be downright dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a powershell script that requires [TFS Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963) and takes an extremely long time to run, and is really kind of embarrassing code because it's the first thing I've written in powershell. You're welcome to grab it from [my bitbucket repository](https://bitbucket.org/nkcraddock/scripts/src). If you fix or improve anything, please send me an update.

All it does recursively go through (almost all) the files from the current path, and run annotate on each one, grab the changeset # from each line and increment a dictionary entry for that changeset, then loops through each changeset and finds the responsible user and adds that changeset's lines into that user's dictionary entry. It spits it out in a html table, so run it like LineCount.ps1 > LineCount.html

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244698%28v=VS.90%29.aspx if you're running a version of SQL capable of using data cubes